# How to skip the Pylint message for function definition in Python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.7, pylint, type-hinting

I have a function definition in my code, which starts with:

```
def pivotIndex(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
```

I installed pylint in Visual Studio Code and now there are tildes symbols beneath the word `List`:

[image]

When running my code, I get an exception:

```
    def pivotIndex(self, nums: List[int]) -> int:
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

How to skip or rectify the pylint error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the [`typing.List` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List):

```
from typing import List
```

Type hinting uses *actual Python objects*. If you don't, type hinters will complain too:

```
$ mypy filename.py
filename.py:1: error: Name 'List' is not defined
filename.py:1: note: Did you forget to import it from "typing"? (Suggestion: "from typing import List")
```

This applies even if you use `from __future__ import annotations` to postpone evaluation of annotations (see [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)), or use a string value with the type hint. You must still import the names as the type hint checker needs to know what exact object they refer to. That's because `List` can otherwise be just about anything, it is *not a built-in name*.

E.g. you could have assigned your own meaning to `List` somewhere

```
List = Union[List, CustomListSubclass]
```

and then importing that object and using that definition of `List` would be a valid (if confusing) type hint.

Note that turning the annotation into a string (`nums: 'List[int]`) may make pylint error go away, you will still get errors when you use type hinting. The tool checking the hints can't resolve the `List` object without the import. Until you add `from typing import List` to the module, you may as well just *remove the type hints* in that case (e.g. `def pivotIndex(self, nums):`).

Comment: Hi @Martijn, thanks for your information, I found this "def pivotIndex(self, nums: 'List[int]') -> int:" and then the message is gone.

Comment: @skyclouder: that.. is not going to work properly, because you now just disabled proper type hints. Yes, using a string annotation works here, but **you still can't use type checking**. Strings work only because Python then postpones resolving the name `List`, but you still haven't actually imported it!

Comment: @skyclouder: you may as well *just remove the type hints* in that case. Why is just adding `from typing import List` at the top of your module an issue?

Comment: @skyclouder That is NOT how you should fix your problem. Please follow the advice given in this answer.